# How to populate file attributes from a directory into a struct vector?

Tags: c++, file, vector, struct

I'm brand new to C++ and I'm trying to learn on my own, so I'm running into a lot of simple issues. Right now I want to look at a directory, containing files that end in ".img", and push only the file name and creation time into a struct vector.

How does a push_back into a vector work? Does each struct pushed back populate into the vector or is it possible to make a mistake and be overwriting the previous push_back? I don't know if I'm over thinking this...

Could someone please take a look at my code and let me know if I'm doing this correctly or where I may need to make changes? Thank you so much!

```
void filterContextByHsiTime(const char *context_path, int hsi_create_time) {

struct contextFileStruct {                                          //Define Struct containing key elements of a file
    double createTime;
    string fileName;
};
std::vector<contextFileStruct> contextVector;                       //Initialize resizable vector array of type contextFileStruct
contextFileStruct tempStruct;
_finddata_t allFiles;                                               //Structure that holds file specific elements

int findFirstContextImage = _findfirst(context_path, &allFiles);    //Int variable holding result of the findfirst function 
                                                                    //where -1 = no image fround and any other number = image found
tempStruct.fileName = allFiles.name;
tempStruct.createTime = allFiles.time_create;
contextVector.push_back(tempStruct);

if (findFirstContextImage != -1 ) {
    int findNextContextImage = 0;                                   //iterator for next context image in dir
    while (findNextContextImage != -1) {
        findNextContextImage = _findnext(findFirstContextImage, &allFiles);
        tempStruct.fileName = allFiles.name;
        tempStruct.createTime = allFiles.time_create;
        contextVector.push_back(tempStruct);
    }
    _findclose(findFirstContextImage);                              //Close findfirst file function to prevent memory leaks
}
else {
    cout << "There are no .img files in this directory!" << endl;   //error handling for when there are no context files
}
```

}

Comment: _How does a push_back into a vector work?_ Did you try reading the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back)?

Comment: Flagged as too broad as you are asking multiple things, none of which are really on topic. If you have questions about the stdlib, read the bountiful documentation online. If you want code review, go to Code Review. If you have a problem, post what it is and what error you get.

Comment: I did read the documentation and see that each element is being appended, but when I run my code it looks like it's replacing it. With that being said, I don't know if I have an error or am looking at the code incorrectly through the debugger.

Comment: Well, you should've mentioned that in your question. You didn't say you were having that problem. You just asked a bunch of general questions that seemed theoretical, without revealing that there was a practical reason that you were unsure.

Comment: I'm sensing attitude from you underscore_d... I stated what I wanted my my program to do, I asked some "general" questions that supported my confusion, and I stated that I wasn't sure if I even had a problem or not. This is normal for someone starting out new without a background. lighten up!

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at it incorrectly in the debugger. Instead of reviewing the populating of the vector, I was just looking at the struct populating and then adding the next file, so it looked as if it was overwriting. Silly error on my part. My code is working as I intended, thanks!